# Book of problems in abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good problem book on Abstract Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174596/good-problem-book-on-abstract-algebra)

What are some books similar to [*Problems in Real Analysis: Advanced Calculus on the Real Axis*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387773789) by Radulescu, Radulescu and Adreescu but with abstract algebra topics?

Comment: Dickson. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Already did a search on google books ( http://www.google.com.br/search?q=problems+in+algebra&btnG=Pesquisar+livros&tbm=bks&tbo=1&hl=pt-BR  ) with appropriate keywords? For example: "Problems in abstract algebra", "problems in algebra."

Answer (score 2):

There is [*Exercises in Algebra*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2884490302) by Kostrikin. Personally I prefer Dummit over this book.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Jasper Loy.