# Algebra analogue of Pólya's "Problems and Theorems in Analysis"

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

I've learned many theorems in analysis but have found the collection of problems in Pólya's *Problems and Theorems in Analysis* to broaden and deepen my knowledge of the subject (along with providing many hours of fun).

Is there a similar book for problems in algebra? I recently took an introductory course whose problems were far too easy. I would like to get better at the subject.

Comment: Related: [Good problem book on Abstract Algebra](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174596/good-problem-book-on-abstract-algebra)

Answer (score 1):

V. B. Alekseev, Abel's Theorem in Problems & Solutions.

http://www.nairanalytics.com/abel.pdf

E. S. Lyapin, A. Ya. Aizenshtat, and M. M. Lesokhin, 
Exercises in Group Theory.

http://hep.fcfm.buap.mx/TTG/libros/Exercises%20in%20Group%20Theory%20by%20E.S.Lyapin....pdf

Comment: The second link is clearly piracy. I do not think it is a good idea to point it out here.

Comment: @Siminore: Thank you, I wrote another address. Is it OK?